# My 2010 VW Golf outside lights went Crazy

Tags: electrical, vw, lights, golf

I was driving the other day an all of a sudden my car started popping up a bunch of warnings in my menu, 10 to be exact. All to do with my outside lights going out  1 headlight, 1 high beam , 1 brake light, 1 back up light, 1 park light & my licence plate tag light are all not working. Can anyone shine so e light on my situation? Cause it's been 2 weeks & I'm still riding with half my lights out

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are all the lights on the same side of the car?